# Using Google Earth Web as an application development platform

Tags: google-earth

I'm looking for an option to use Google Earth Web as a platform to develop a custom application, which would involve reviewing/editing a large list of map locations and connections between them.

The 3D content of GEW would be great for this. However, I could not find any documentation of using it for this purpose (similar to how we could use Leaflet or OpenLayers for 2D content).  Is using GEW for building custom apps possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (early 2021), Google Earth for Web (v9.x) does not provide an API, so it's not possible to embed it in a website or application.  If you can do something that implements the required functionality in KML (using the features on the map and interactive content in the balloons & panels), that might be a possibility.